# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module occuring after restarting machine

Tags: react, hardhat, typescript

I am attempting to create a simple react site using typescript hardhat. I can get the full stack created, compile contracts and view the site to interact with the greeter contract. After restarting (or possibly just leaving editor I need to confirm this) I will be met with this error

```
An unexpected error occurred:

/home/notes/Programming/Yapeswap/yape-nft-site/hardhat.config.ts:1
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/notes/Programming/Yapeswap/yape-nft-site/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1371:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/notes/Programming/Yapeswap/yape-nft-site/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1374:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

I'm at an absolute loss as to why this set of events would cause this error. If I try and change the order of the imports every import will have the same error.

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file? If not, create one with the content suggested here: https://hardhat.org/guides/typescript.html If you do have one, check that the "module" option is set to "commonjs"

Comment: That was the solution! My autogenerated ```tsconfig.json``` got set to ```"module": "esnext"``` somehow. Thank you!